# Distinguish between iPhone web browser and iPhone app user agent

Tags: iphone, http, user-agent

What is the best way to distinguish on a server between a request that came from an iPhone through the web browser vs through an iphone with an app written in objective c? What differences do I look for in the user agent string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe user agents from the Safari app start with "Mozilla", while user agents from apps start with the name of the app.

Answer (score 35):

It seems that iPhone Apps using the UIWebKit HTTP request component have user agent string like the following

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0_1 like Mac OS X; fr-fr) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8A306
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_1_2 like Mac OS X; fr-fr) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7D11
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_1_3 like Mac OS X; fr-fr) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7E18
```

While Safari on iPhone has mostly the [same string](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW3) but ending with " Safari/XXX"

However, it is also possible to [change the user agent of UIWebKit](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/04/07/changing-the-headers-for-uiwebkit-http-requests/) then there is no guarantee that you'll grab every iPhone app by proceeding this way.

Comment: In addition to "Mobile/XXX" and "Safari/XXX", Chrome for iOS adds a "CriOS/XXX" part to the UA strng. See https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

Answer (score -4):

Indeed the user agent will be different.

in PHP, you can find out with this: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']