# Regex detect Iphone App User agent (not web browser from Iphone) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, user-agent

I have to differentiate between an incoming request from an Iphone App and an incoming request from an Iphone/Ipad (apple mobile device) web browser.
As stated in this question [Iphone Web Browser vs Iphone Web Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305867/distinguish-between-iphone-web-browser-and-iphone-app-user-agent) and for what I have seen in my logs, the difference between both user agents is that when coming from a web browser, the word "Safari" is added at the end.
So my question is:

How would I create a regex similar to this one:

```
/Apple.*Mobile.*Safari/
```

But instead of .*Safari, making sure that Safari is not there. So I know the petition comes from the app.

Comment: You know the rule "never trust the client"?

Comment: Yes, I have heard of it, but I would love to hear more, or suggestions on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with en expression like:

```
Apple.*Mobile(?!.*Safari)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  But what if I would like to know that Safari doesn't exist AFTER Mobile?