# Enable API consumption only for my mobile App

Tags: node.js, api

I have an API in node js that i use as source of a mobile app.
Is there some way to keep the data available only to my app and not for other apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, to a degree - you can use some sort of cryptographic authentication scheme, though a determined attacker will hunt through your .apk until they extract the keys.

Comment: What about some sort of user auth scheme? I suppose a user could take their creds and use them to connect from another app... but they would already have been authorized to use your API anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305867/distinguish-between-iphone-web-browser-and-iphone-app-user-agent). See if you can use the user agent to restrict the access to your app only.

Of course it is easy for someone to modify the user agent and make a request. If you are concerned about this you might need better form of authentication.

Comment: Certainly user agent by itself is problematic, but it may be part of a solution. As a first check, you could throw out anything that doesn't match your supported devices, then take a closer look at the traffic that does.