# How do I check whether the user agent is from the mobile app or mobile web?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, user-agent, mobile-application

How do I identify if an ad was rendered from within the mobile application or rendered on a mobile web browser.

What kind of alternatives exist?

a. Can I distinguish traffic from app or mobile web based on the user agent.

Sample user agent(s) are here as follows, but I am unable to distinguish

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D201
```

b. I also referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305867/distinguish-between-iphone-web-browser-and-iphone-app-user-agent) which discussed same problem.

Comment: It depends on what user agent value you have pass from using mobile app.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/12999154/641062